# Chart of iOS UIKit inheritance

Tags: ios, inheritance, uiview

I'm looking for a document or chart that might show me all the inheritance in `UIKit`.  For instance, what are all the objects that inherit from `UIView`?  What are the objects that inherit from `UIControl`?  Etc.

I know that at the bottom of a given page in the docs, like `UIControl`, I can see that it inherits from `UIView`.  But for my purpose, it would be better if I could look at `UIView` and see all the things that inherit from it.

Something in the Apple documentation would be great, but if such a thing doesn't exist, some unofficial doc someone might have created would be fine too.

Thanks!

Comment: Open Xcode with a project that uses UIKit, show the symbol navigator (cmd-2), remove the "show only project defined symbols". There you have it, all symbols in a hierarchical or flat display.

Comment: @iMoses That definitely worked for me and is a great tip.  You should form it as an answer.

Comment: Just did, and threw in a screenshot for anyone having issues finding the toggle button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Xcode with a project that uses UIKit, and then show the symbol navigator (⌘2).
Uncheck the button for 'Show only project-defined symbols'.
There you have it - all symbols in a hierarchical or flat display.
[image]